# Alternate video type in JWPlayer XML config

Tags: html, jwplayer

Videos are streamed via RMTP with my player, but that is only available on the flash version. For iPad and suchlike, JWPlayer falls back to the HTML5 version, which requires a different file. It is available, but I would like to only serve one `.xml` file and the player to choose the file automatically. The docs say I can have a `<provider>` tag but does not tell me how to have several of those.

I know that this can be done in the `.setup()` function, kind of. But since I provide an `.xml` file for the video file there, I would like the alternative video there.

It is required to use RMTP when it is available, the other HTML5-compatible file is only to use when flash is not available nor installable. The version of JWPlayer is 5.10.

Comment: I'm afraid if you are going to be using a playlist, you can't have the fallback occur inside of the XML file itself, you would need two, one for each mode, in 5.10, here is some reference - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/18508/jw-embedder-modes, and an example - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/18530/embedding-an-rtmp-stream-with-an-html5-fallback, you would just use two xml files here in this case.

Comment: @EthanLongTail It's not really a playlist, since it only has one file... I kind of wanted to avoid two files so people won't find the http version, it's too easy to download.

Comment: Well, HTTP/HTML5 doesn't really have much security at all I'm afraid. You really are going to need to provide two files, if the first can't be viewed in HTML5 natively, and RTMP security is also pretty easily circumvented with tools like StreamTransport, etc. Generally, if people want your content badly enough, they are going to try to figure out a way to get it if they are tech savvy enough. There isn't anything preventing people from just using CamTasia or a screen recorder and just stealing the content that way. There is only so much you can do here, I'm afraid.

Comment: @EthanLongTail Do you recommend a UserAgent check or anything for iPad/iPhone? They're the only ones without flash, anyway.

Comment: You can certainly do that, that will work. However, our player's modes feature already takes care of all of that for you - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/18508/jw-embedder-modes